# How to aggregate count of nodes at every depth of variable length relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

### Data structure

I have `User` and `Organisation` nodes in my graph stored in neo4j.

A `User` can refer another `User` (relationship: `REFFERED`)
A `User` can subscribe to an `Organisation` (relationship: `SUBSCRIBED_TO`)

### Goal

I want to find the referrals that are coming from one user (eg. friends-of-friends-of-n*/referral-of-referral-of-n*) and the subscriptions those users made, ordered by each level of depth.

### Problem

I have following cypher query:

```
MATCH p= (start:User {uid: 1})-[:REFERRED|SUBSCRIBED_TO*]->(end)
WITH *, relationships(p) as rel
WITH *, size(rel) as Depth
WITH Depth, type(rel[Depth - 1]) as Type, count(p) as Count
RETURN Depth, Type, Count
```

Returning:

```
╒═══════╤══════════════════════╤═══════╕
│"Depth"│"Type"                │"Count"│
╞═══════╪══════════════════════╪═══════╡
│1      │"REFERRED"            │10     │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│2      │"REFERRED"            │100    │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│3      │"REFERRED"            │1000   │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│4      │"REFERRED"            │10000  │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│4      │"SUBSCRIBED_TO"       │6      │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│2      │"SUBSCRIBED_TO"       │2      │
└───────┴──────────────────────┴───────┘
```

And the results are correct. However, if I want to pass on `end` in `WITH` to use a `UNION` to `MATCH` a second result with the `end` value, my result set changes.

Query:

```
MATCH p= (start:User {uid: 1})-[:REFERRED|SUBSCRIBED_TO*]->(end)
WITH *, relationships(p) as rel
WITH *, size(rel) as Depth
WITH Depth, type(rel[Depth - 1]) as Type, count(p) as Count, end
RETURN Depth, Type, Count
```

Result:

```
╒═══════╤══════════════════════╤═══════╕
│"Depth"│"Type"                │"Count"│
╞═══════╪══════════════════════╪═══════╡
│1      │"REFERRED"            │1      │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│2      │"REFERRED"            │1      │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│3      │"REFERRED"            │1      │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│4      │"REFERRED"            │1      │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│4      │"REFERRED"            │1      │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│4      │"REFERRED"            │1      │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│4      │"REFERRED"            │1      │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤

...
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│4      │"SUBSCRIBED_TO"       │2      │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│4      │"SUBSCRIBED_TO"       │2      │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│4      │"SUBSCRIBED_TO"       │1      │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼───────┤
│4      │"SUBSCRIBED_TO"       │1      │
...
```

### Question

So my question has two parts:

1. How would one most efficiently construct this kind of query with cypher?
2. What paradigm or what principle of cypher makes it that the result gets spread over multiple rows when `end` is passed along

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) like `COLLECT` use the non-aggregating terms in the same `WITH` (or `RETURN`) clause as `grouping keys`. You should read the documentation for more details.

Here is a query that might be suitable for your use case:

```
MATCH p = (:User {uid: 1})-[:REFERRED|SUBSCRIBED_TO*]->(end)
WITH
  LENGTH(p) AS depth,
  TYPE(LAST(RELATIONSHIPS(p))) AS type,
  COLLECT(end) as ends
RETURN depth, type, SIZE(ends) AS count, ends
```

`depth`, `type`, and `count` should have your expected values. And `ends` will be a collection of the `end` nodes that have the same `depth` and `type` values.

Comment: `grouping keys` was what I was looking for! I felt like there was some implicit grouping going on but couldn't put my finger on it. Must have read over it, thanks!